# Vuejs -- Computed property not being defined on the instance

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm fairly new to VueJS and I am having difficulties getting a child component to work properly.

So first off, I had some code in a "view" that I realized I wanted to use more than once, so I began to factor that code out into a separate component, but I ran into this problem:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method `"<feedbackCallback|stateCallback|submitCallback>"` is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

My setup is the following:

- Vue 2.4.2
- Webpack 3.5.5
- Bootstrap-Vue 1.0.0
- Vue-Router 2.7.0
- I'm also using Single File Components

I'm going to call the file for the "view" ViewA and the file for the "component" "CompA"

ViewA with the parts removed that weren't going into a separate component:

```
<template>
  [...]
  <b-form @submit="submitCallback">
    <b-form-group
      id="groupID"
      description=""
      label="Set Thing Here" :feedback="feedbackCallback"
      :state="stateCallback">
      <b-form-input
        id="inputID" :state="stateCallback"
        v-model.trim="thing">
      </b-form-input>
    </b-form/group>

    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
  </b-form>
  [...]
</template>

<script>
export default {
  [...]
  data () {
    return {
      thing: '',
      [...]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    stateCallback () {
      return 'invalid'
    },
    feedbackCallback () {
      return 'Please enter a valid thing'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitCallback (event) {
      [...]
    }
  },
  [...]
</script>
```

Now, I moved these guys into CompA.

This is the code now where I'm getting the error:

ViewA:

```
<template>
  [...]
  <comp-a v-model.trim="thing" :thingvalue="thing"></comp-a>
  [...]
</template>

<script>
import CompA from '../components/CompA'

export default {
  name: 'view-a'
  components: {
    CompA
  },
  data () {
    return {
      thing: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

CompA:

```
<template>
  <b-form @submit="submitCallback">
    <b-form-group
      id="groupID"
      description=""
      label="Set Thing Here" :feedback="feedbackCallback"
      :state="stateCallback">
      <b-form-input
        id="inputID" :state="stateCallback"
        :value="thingvalue">
      </b-form-input>
    </b-form/group>

    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
  </b-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    thingvalue: {
      type: String
      required: true
    }
  },  
  computed: {
    stateCallback () {
      return 'invalid'
    },
    feedbackCallback () {
      return 'Please enter a valid thing'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitCallback (event) {
      [...]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You might notice when I moved the code over, I changed the `v-model.trim="thing"` to `:value="thing"`. I was getting the same error with thing until I did this.

Now is there something I'm missing? I've been digging a lot to try and understand. I even looked at some of bootstrap-vue's code to see if they do anything funky. But it turns out they have some computed properties being used in a very similar fashion. So I'm not understanding where the problem is happening. Let me know if you need more information.

## Update

I'm more convinced that there is something going on with WebPack and VueJS as I'm not finding any definition of these properties/methods in the bundled up js file.

Comment: Not sure about your error but you shouldn't be binding a component `prop` to a `value` or `v-model`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: Also, try reloading the page. Due to Webpack's hot-reload, you may have simply gotten that error at some point in the past while you were editing your files. It may not even be present anymore

Comment: @Phil How does it work then? So in this case I have `thing` from ViewA (which is the parent component) binding to the `prop` thingvalue from CompA (which is the child). I wanted to use this in the next component down. So now CompA becomes a parent component to the `b-form-input` component. Am I supposed to just set the `prop` to some `data` property and put a `watch` on the `prop` or something like that?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Pass props in, emit events out

Comment: @Phil I've tried that. Even done a force reload. I'll also tried in an incognito window. But I could try deleting the cache and try that.

Comment: Try re-compiling.

Comment: @JericoPulvera I've also tried that. But I'll do it again.

Comment: also please check Vue dev tools if the computed property is being loaded.

Comment: @Phil Maybe I'm misunderstanding something... So let's say you have Parent1 -- Child1/Parent2 -- Child2. So Child1 is also Parent2 just assumes that role with Child2. So Parent1 passes props into Child1 then I'm wanting to pass those on further to Child2. Does Child1 not now assume the role of parent in this case?

Comment: @JericoPulvera How is that done?

Comment: @gshawm Vue dev tools is available in chrome as an extension.

Comment: @gshawm did you get down to here in the docs ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events. Also see this forum post about nested components ~ https://forum.vuejs.org/t/recommended-approach-to-emit-an-event-from-a-nested-child/10197. You can save a bunch of boilerplate by using the `.sync` modifier

Comment: @Phil I did not read that part. Must've missed it. thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well turns out it was simply a dumb mistake on my part. Did not have a closing script tag. Eslint wasn't catching either (maybe there is a setting to make sure it does), so it compiled with webpack just fine. Lesson: Always remember your closing tag!

Comment: in my case, I had two computed:{} defined. the later one must have overwritten the first one.

Comment: had the same issue, realised I didn't spell "computed" correctly ‍♂️